# How to fill a planar inside selected vertices?

Tags: tools

I am trying to find a way how quickly create planar shapes inside selected vertices. Is it possible to get the same result with 1-2 actions or some addon like in the image below?

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure how Blender could guess how you want to fill, you need to extrude and fill the faces